# kendo UI error $0 is not defined

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo version: "2016.1.112" . And google Chrome Version 50.0.2661.94 m
    I am facing error .its console error **Uncaught ReferenceError: $0 is not defined**

it is referencing in below kendo script:

```
 setTimeout(function(){
            // just in case devtools opens as a result of "Inspect
            // Element", make sure we update window.$K if necessary
            if ($0) {
                tools.inspectKendoWidget($0);
            }
        }, 300);
```

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: there is no code error. Error is from Kendo UI i think . In every page same error is coming

Comment: It might be possible that the error is from kendoUI but I want to reproduce your issue so we will try to resolve your issue or report the bug to kendo-ui team.

Comment: ok, please notify what the answer if you get solution

Answer (score 2):

That issue is due the the KendoUI inspector Extension  which you have in your chrome as extension. Either remove it or wait for an  update from the Telerik team to fix their extension.

However that error should not have any impact on your application.

Comment: I have the same with the "2015.3.930" + Inspector

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the inspector and the error has gone.
Go to extensions option menu and uncheck the inspector.